# Why would a program written with ArcGIS 9.3 objects no longer work when upgraded to ArcGIS 10?

Tags: c#, exception, migration, arcgis

Sometime last year, when we used ArcGIS 9.3, I wrote a C# program in Visual Studio 2008 to go through all MXD files in a folder, check all the layer sources, and replace them if they are either wrong or don't exist. It worked flawlessly.

At some point later last year, we upgraded to ArcGIS 10. We have now arrived at that time of year to fix any faulty sources again. So I went in the source code, fixed the binding, and re-referenced any Arc sources; this was done to make it compatible with the newer ArcGIS 10 objects. The program works normally on any MXDs that were made with ArcGIS 10, but fails with the following error on any MXDs made in ArcGIS 9.3:

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type
'ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer'. This operation failed because the
QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID
'{40A9E885-5533-11D0-98BE-00805F7CED21}' failed due to the following
error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002
(E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

This error occurs on any casting of an ILayer to an IFeatureLayer. For example, the second line here:

```
ILayer layer = ...;
IFeatureLayer featureLayer = (IFeatureLayer)layer;
IFeatureClass featureClass = featureLayer.FeatureClass;
```

I needed to be able to access that Feature Class.

So why does this program work on the newer MXDs and not the old ones?

Thanks.

EDIT: Here's what I'm doing (slightly simplified and without a function call):

```
string[] featureClassNames = {"Building_Anno", ...};
IEnumLayer pEnumLayer = map.get_Layers(null, true);

for (int i = 0; i < featureClassNames.Length; i++)
{
    pEnumLayer.Reset();

    ILayer layer = null;

    while ((layer = pEnumLayer.Next()) != null)
    { /* stuff */ }

    if (layer == null) continue;

    IFeatureLayer featureLayer = (IFeatureLayer)layer;
    IFeatureClass oldFeatureClass = null;

    try
    {
        oldFeatureClass = featureLayer.FeatureClass;
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException) { }

    featureLayer.FeatureClass = newFeatureClass;

    if (oldFeatureClass == null)
        mapAdmin2.FireChangeFeatureClass(oldFeatureClass, newFeatureClass);
    else if (oldFeatureClass.Equals(newFeatureClass))
        return "Nope: Same source.";
    else
        return "Nope: Source already exists.";

} // end of for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your older document contains layers which are not feature layers.  For example, if you have a raster in your MXD, it will implement `ILayer` by not `IFeatureLayer`, since the [RasterLayer CoClass](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/RasterLayerClass_Class/001200000s7q000000/) doesn't implement `IFeatureLayer`.

The way this is typically handled is by checking before using the type, ie:

```
ILayer layer = ...;
IFeatureLayer featureLayer = layer as IFeatureLayer; // use as keyword
if (featureLayer != null)
{
   // You have a feature class layer:
   IFeatureClass fc = featureLayer.FeatureClass;

}
```

Comment: I can't find any documentation on why something would suddenly no longer have feature class functionality. How would I get the feature class of something if it no longer is one? I edited my question to add more information what exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: @Fenix It's more if your mxd has a layer that isn't a feature class type (like a raster or graphics layer)

Comment: But I didn't add any layers to the old ones; all old layers were easily converted to feature classes. The casting fails with every single layer.

Comment: @Fenix I'd debug, and check to see why you're getting that then

Comment: I've tried; that's why I'm here. I can't even look at what is in any of the variables because it "times out" for some reason (I assumed it was because there was too much data).

Answer (score 0):

```
How to Delete Field in featureclass like(cable,meter or Support structure...etc) the code is given below.

Class1.cs file

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework;


namespace PATICULAR_FIELD_DELETED
{
    class Class1
    {
        public static IApplication pApplication = null;
        public static IMxDocument pMxDcoument = null;
        public static IMap pMap = null;
    }
}


PARTICULARFIELDDELETED.cs file

using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.BaseClasses;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.CATIDs;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;

    enter code here

namespace PATICULAR_FIELD_DELETED
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for PARTICULARFIELDDELETED.
    /// </summary>
    [Guid("cb10e93e-58d9-4c81-9107-2eda417a3770")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ProgId("PATICULAR_FIELD_DELETED.PARTICULARFIELDDELETED")]
    public sealed class PARTICULARFIELDDELETED : BaseCommand
    {
        #region COM Registration Function(s)
        [ComRegisterFunction()]
        [ComVisible(false)]
        static void RegisterFunction(Type registerType)
        {
            // Required for ArcGIS Component Category Registrar support
            ArcGISCategoryRegistration(registerType);

            //
            // TODO: Add any COM registration code here
            //
        }
        [ComUnregisterFunction()]
        [ComVisible(false)]
        static void UnregisterFunction(Type registerType)
        {
            // Required for ArcGIS Component Category Registrar support
            ArcGISCategoryUnregistration(registerType);

            //
            // TODO: Add any COM unregistration code here
            //
        }
        #region ArcGIS Component Category Registrar generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for ArcGIS Component Category registration -
        /// Do not modify the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private static void ArcGISCategoryRegistration(Type registerType)
        {
            string regKey = string.Format("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\CLSID\\{{{0}}}", registerType.GUID);
            MxCommands.Register(regKey);

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for ArcGIS Component Category unregistration -
        /// Do not modify the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private static void ArcGISCategoryUnregistration(Type registerType)
        {
            string regKey = string.Format("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\CLSID\\{{{0}}}", registerType.GUID);
            MxCommands.Unregister(regKey);

        }

        #endregion
        #endregion

        private IApplication m_application;
        public PARTICULARFIELDDELETED()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Define values for the public properties
            //
            base.m_category = "PARTICULARFIELDDELETED"; //localizable text
            base.m_caption = "PARTICULARFIELDDELETED";  //localizable text
            base.m_message = "PARTICULARFIELDDELETED";  //localizable text 
            base.m_toolTip = "PARTICULARFIELDDELETED";  //localizable text 
            base.m_name = "PARTICULARFIELDDELETED";   //unique id, non-localizable (e.g. "MyCategory_ArcMapCommand")

            try
            {
                //
                // TODO: change bitmap name if necessary
                //
                string bitmapResourceName = "PARTICULARFIELDDELETED.bmp";
                base.m_bitmap = new Bitmap(GetType(), bitmapResourceName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message, "Invalid Bitmap");
            }
        }

        #region Overridden Class Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when this command is created
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hook">Instance of the application</param>
        public override void OnCreate(object hook)
        {
            if (hook == null)
                return;

            m_application = hook as IApplication;

            //Disable if it is not ArcMap
            if (hook is IMxApplication)
                base.m_enabled = true;
            else
                base.m_enabled = false;

            // TODO:  Add other initialization code
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when this command is clicked
        /// </summary>
        public override void OnClick()
        {
            // TODO: Add PARTICULARFIELDDELETED.OnClick implementation
            Class1.pApplication = m_application;
            Class1.pMxDcoument = m_application.Document as IMxDocument;
            Class1.pMap = Class1.pMxDcoument.ActivatedView.FocusMap;
            if (Class1.pMap.LayerCount == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Layers are Found", "PARTICULARFIELDDELETED", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            IFeatureLayer pMeterFeatureLayer = ListLayers(Class1.pMxDcoument, "METER");
            if (pMeterFeatureLayer == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            IFeatureClass featureclass = pMeterFeatureLayer.FeatureClass;

            CreateFieldsCollectionForTable(featureclass, "AssetID");

        }
        public IFeatureLayer ListLayers(IMxDocument pMxDocument, string layerName)
        {
            UID puid = new UID();
            puid.Value = "{E156D7E5-22AF-11D3-9F99-00C04F6BC78E}";
            IEnumLayer penumlayer = pMxDocument.ActiveView.FocusMap.get_Layers(puid, true);
            penumlayer.Reset();
            IFeatureLayer featureLayer = penumlayer.Next() as IFeatureLayer;
            while (featureLayer != null)
            {
                if (featureLayer.Name.ToUpper() == layerName)
                {
                    break;
                }
                featureLayer = penumlayer.Next() as IFeatureLayer;
            }
            return featureLayer;

        }

        public void CreateFieldsCollectionForTable(IFeatureClass featureclass, string fieldname)
        {
            // Create a fields collection.
            try
            IFields fields = featureclass.Fields;
            IField field = fields.get_Field(fields.FindField("AssetID"));
            featureclass.DeleteField(field);
            MessageBox.Show("We have deleted field successfully", 
"ParticularFieldDeleted", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```